# FlatList or ScrollView don't work when children are wrapped with Swipeable

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, react-swipeable-views

I have a FlatList, and each item inside the FlatList is wrapped with Swipeable from react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable.
It appears as if Swipeable cancels the gestures, and doesn't allow the FlatList to scroll if my finger is on a Swipeable element.
Is there any way around it? So far I haven't been able to make them both work together properly.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers, turns out that the problem was that the entire view was wrapped inside a DismissableKeyboard component. I removed it, and now everything is working as it should.

Comment: I'm not sure, why are you facing that issue. I tried a quick `snack` example and it worked like a charm. maybe try referring this example https://snack.expo.io/@adamgrzybowski/react-native-gesture-handler-demo

Answer (score 0):

Check your import statement, perhaps if you import `FlatList` and `ScrollView` from `react-gesture-handler` instead of `react-native` they will work with Swipeable or vice versa if you you're importing them from `react-gesture-handler`, try importing them form `react-native`